# ArrayList to JTable

Tags: java, sql, swing, arraylist, jtable

I'm trying to load data in a JTable from a SQL srv. I'm experiencing trouble when trying to convert the ArrayList and loading it in to the JTable.
When I try the code below the table that should show the list is showing "[L].java.lang.String@bf053f"

```
 private void searchCourseGrades() {
StudentsWithGradeTable.setModel(dtmCoursesGrades);
String ccode = SearchCidTextfield.getText();

try {
    dtmCoursesGrades.setDataVector(
        controller.findAllStudentsFromStudied(ccode),
        coursesGradesColumns);

    if (ccode.equals("")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
        "Please enter a Course Code");

    } else {
    dtmCoursesGrades.setRowCount(0);
    dtmCoursesGrades.fireTableDataChanged();
    Studied findStudentFromStudied = null;
    findStudentFromStudied = controller
        .findCourseFromStudied(ccode);

    String[] crsgr = new String[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < crsgr.length; i++) {
    crsgr[0] = findStudentFromStudied.getSpnr();
    crsgr[1] = findStudentFromStudied.getGrade();
    dtmCoursesGrades.addRow(new Object []{crsgr});
    dtmCoursesGrades.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    }

} catch (SQLException exception) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
        "Cannot find a course with Course Code " + ccode
            + ". Please try a new number.");
}

}
```

The controller that the MainForm refers to looks like this:

```
private String[][] finishedArrayList(ArrayList<Studied> finished) {
String[][] finishedStudents = new String[finished.size()][3];

for (int i = 0; i < finished.size(); i++) {
    Studied finish = finished.get(i);

    finishedStudents[i][0] = finish.getSpnr();
    finishedStudents[i][1] = finish.getCcode();
    finishedStudents[i][2] = finish.getGrade();
}

return finishedStudents;
}

public String[][] findAllStudentsFromStudied(String ccode)
    throws SQLException {
return finishedArrayList(dal.findAllStudentsFromStudied(ccode));
```

and the DAL that the controller refers to looks like this:

```
 public ArrayList<Studies> findAllStudentsFromStudies(String ccode)
    throws SQLException {

ArrayList<Studies> stlist = new ArrayList<Studies>();
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Studies WHERE ccode = '" + ccode + "'";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr);

while (rs.next()) {
    Studies st = new Studies();
    st.setSpnr(rs.getString(1));

    stlist.add(st);
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
return stlist;
}
```

Comment: And what kind of trouble might that be? If exceptions, give us the stacktrace, for others describe in detail what happens or not happens.

Comment: Please reduce your problem to the ArrayList jTable part. No need for database queries for they have nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try `dtmCoursesGrades.addRow(new Object []{crsgr[0], crsgr[1]});` instead of `dtmCoursesGrades.addRow(new Object []{crsgr});`

Comment: When I change this i receive 
Student ID column:
8
8
Grade column:
E
E

Which is not correct, I have several grades with different student IDs..

Comment: @SLI It's data returned by `controller.findCourseFromStudied(ccode);`. Try debug more.